# Is the plastic sleeve optional for a GXP bottom bracket install?

Tags: bottom-bracket, sram

I took my frame to a bike shop to have the threads chased on the drive side.  When I got home, I realized that they didn't install the plastic sleeve (because I didn't give it to them).  They didn't say anything about it, so is that just to keep out dust/grime?

And what's the official word for that plastic sleeve?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about the things that look like thin, wide plastic washers that go on the outer part of both sides of the bottom bracket, they are called **bearing seals**.

Assuming that you are saying that the bearing seals were not installed, then I would absolutely remove the cranks and install them.  They are designed to keep most of the road gunk out of your bottom bracket, helping it to last significantly longer.

If you have the appropriate crank puller then you can do it yourself.  Remove the cranks, put a light coat of grease on the inner side of the seals and then press them firmly into the bottom bracket.  They should seat firmly into an outer groove on the bottom bracket.

If you are talking about the clear plastic cylinder in the pic then I don't know what it is officially called, but I think you can do with out it. Not having it may mean that you need to check and tighten your bottom bracket more frequently, but I don't believe it's necessary.

Comment: I was referring to the clear plastic cylinder.  I've since found other forums where people are saying it isn't necessary but good to have.  I'll put it back in the next time I work on the bike.

Comment: That's what I would do - there is usually a drain hole in the frame, and the cylinder will help keep gunk from getting into the BB that way.

Answer (score 4):

I took a quick look at the Truvativ warranty information and the warranty is void if the BB is not installed properly. Since it's not currently installed properly if anything happens to it then you've got no warranty technically.

Comment: good to know, although i'm outside the warranty (the frame is new...not the bottom bracket).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idae, but I just forgot to reinsert mine after cleaing my bb. My guess is that it keeps your bike frame clean from water that enters from outside via the hollow tech technology. Which mean water can enter the hole in your crank.

I'm no bike expert, but I believe it does not effect the crank or bb functionally. So no you do not need it, but yes you do want to keep water out of your frame. But if you don't plan on keeping the bike forever it does not matter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You have a reasonable hypothesis, but you're basically agreeing with what the OP already guessed.  The question was about getting confirmation from manufacturer information or another reputable source, so just posting your guess doesn't really answer the question.